# Installed cygwin but not able to run C programs

Tags: c, gcc, cygwin

I am trying to write some C code and execute it through Cygwin command line interface using the below command but it throws me an error. I selected the gcc package when i have installed the Cygwin utility. Please kindly share your thoughts regarding the same. Thank you.

**$ gcc HelloWorld.cpp -o HelloWorld
-sh: gcc: command not found**

Comment: Re-run the setup.exe and make sure you have it selected to be installed?

Comment: Install [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/)

Comment: Cygwin won't install gcc by default, you have to select the packages you need. If I were you I'd use MinGW, programs compiled with Cygwin will have Cygwin dependencies.

Comment: I just installed mingw but where do I run my code?

Comment: @David I already selected the respective packages and tried installing but it doesn't work..

Comment: I've never had problems geting cygwin's gcc to work, you might try a different version other than the default.  I currently have 4.8.2-3 installed and it works fine.  I'm using the 64 bit version of cygwin if that helps.

Comment: Can you help me out in installing some compiler. I have TV with me.

Comment: I guess you're on windows. Check if the gcc's bin folder is there in system's environment variable. If not you might want to add it.